# How to use Max and Group By in an NHibernate query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

How would I do the following query using NHibernate?

```
SELECT ClientId, MAX(Id)
FROM Items
GROUP BY ClientId;
```

Comment: Well, I'm don't know too much about _NHibernate_ but is this depends on your mapping?

Comment: Which query API do you prefer? Query (Linq), QueryOver, HQL or ICriteria?

Comment: i prefer Linq but solutions in QueryOver or ICriteria would be fine too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to work it out, was more simple than I thought in the end:

```
            var result = from item in session.Linq<Item>()
                         group item by item.ClientId
                         into itemGroups
                         select new
                             {
                                 id = itemGroups.Key,
                                 max = itemGroups.Max(er => er.Id)
                             };
```

Answer (score 0):

See chapter 14, 15 and 16 of the NHibernate reference for the three query API's of NHibernate.

You can also use LINQ queries over NHibernate. This might be the easiest alternative to start with. Use the `Query<MyType>()` extension method for `ISession` to get an `IQueryable`.